# Can't write/Insert to Amazon Redshift database table with PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to write new data, ie insert, into an Amazon Redshift database using PDOs in PHP.  The database is just redshift alone and not MySQL or PostGRESQL based.  I've been able to connect and do a simple select * and print the results with PDOs, but I'm not able to write data to the database.  I've also been able to read and insert with ODBC_prepare/odbc_execute, so I don't think it's a database set up issue, but the errors I get make no sense.

I get this error when I try my code and I haven't found any ref'n to this error anywhere:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10920 [Amazon][ODBC] (10920) No data can be obtained from an input parameter whose value has already been pushed down.

I've tried this:

```
$column_id_number= 9999;
$column2= "IGOT99PDOISSUES";
$query = 'INSERT into table (column_id_number, column2) VALUES (:column_id_number, :column2)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_id_number', $column_id_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':column2', $column2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

And I've tried 2 diff query syntaxes:

```
$query = 'INSERT into table (column_id_number, column2) VALUES (:column_id_number, :column2)';
//$query = 'INSERT into web_app.stg_wellness_random (column_id_number, column2) VALUES (?,?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':column_id_number' => $column_id_number, 'column2' => $column2]);
```

I've contemplated stick with ODBC queries, but I want to use PDO's because it seems like that's just best practice and the prepared statements are a good defense against SQL injection.  It seems as if ODBC_prepare/execute doesn't have prepared statements or doesn't do much against SQL inject?  (I'd appreciate it if anybody could clarify this, everything I've googled is vague).

(I'm not a backend expert so please excuse the imprecise vocab).

Comment: Side-note: Amazon Redshift presents itself as PostgreSQL v8, so if you can connect to PostgreSQL then you can connect to Redshift.

Comment: What is the error when you use PDOs? Does the INSERT give an error? It might be that the data is not being committed.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein when I do an insert with the PDOs, i get the error I mentioned above "No data can be obtained from an input parameter whose value has already been pushed down.".
2. When I run print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());, i dont have postgresql listed though?  I have mysql, odbc, and sqlite (I didn't install/set up the database, should I have them install something else?)